# How to make autoconf check to see if -R can be passed to flex?

Tags: autoconf, flex-lexer

Apparently gnuflex on MacOS & Linux requires the `-R` option or `%option reentrant` to generate a reentrant scanner, but on FreeBSD it generates a reentrant scanner by default and throws an error if the `-R` or `%option reentrant` are provided. I'd like to have autoconf automatically check to see if `gnuflex` allows the -R option and, if so, provide it. It's not clear to me how I can make autoconf test for this. My guess is that I should run gnuflex on a null file with the -R and check the result code and set some kind of variable, and then add it to the FLEX options, but I'm not really sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you've set `$FLEX`, probably with a combination of `AC_ARG_VAR` and `AC_PATH_PROG`.

```
AC_CACHE_CHECK([whether $FLEX supports -R],
               [my_cv_prog_flex_dash_r],
               [mv_cv_prog_flex_dash_r=no
                echo '%%' | "$FLEX" -R && my_cv_prog_flex_dash_r=yes
                rm -f lex.yy.c])
AS_IF([test $my_cv_prog_flex_dash_r = yes], [FLEX="$FLEX -R"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing. It's more readable than @Jack Kelly's, and it doesn't create a side variable...

```
## Determine if we can use flex -R                                                                                       
if eval "echo %% | $FLEX -R -t > /dev/null 2>&1"
then
  AC_MSG_NOTICE([$FLEX supports -R])
else
  AC_MSG_ERROR([$FLEX does not support -R.  Please get a modern version of gnu flex])
fi
```

Comment: 1. It's not necessarily fatal if flex doesn't support -R. 2. You should be using `AC_MSG_CHECKING`/`AC_MSG_RESULT` when making `configure` check for something`. 3. The "side variable" is used in caching, which speeds up future runs of `configure` (if it was invoked with `-C`).

Comment: For my program it's fatal. Do you think that I should let the script run but then throw a compile error?

Comment: That's not how I read your question. It read to me like you could run FreeBSD flex without -R or gnuflex with -R to get a reentrant scanner, generate your lexer and build it normally. (I know you're only using autoconf, but did you know that automake's flex support distributes the generated lexer in the tarball? That might be an option, too.)

Comment: It's confusing. The version on FreeBSD is actually 15 years out of date. That version says to use the C++ scanner to make something that's reentrant and it lacks the -R option. The current version says that the C++ scanner is experimental, that it never worked properly, that it might be removed, and that you should use the -R scanner to make a reentrant scanner. So pretty much my code is asking for -R and if it is not there it's rejecting. But I do like your solution a lot. Thanks!

Comment: In any case, I suggest you accept at least one of the answers :-).